# How to run a cron job every minute but at random seconds?

Tags: cron, cpanel

Hello i have 2 php scripts needs to run at every minute, but since they are using a social network api, my api keys get banned quickly, they do all things at first few seconds of a minute and this is why they are getting banned..

So i need a way to run these scripts at random seconds, but i couldnt make it work.

I am currently using cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, for googlers out there

```
4-59/* * * * *  (sleep $(($RANDOM\%40+10))) && php /home/user/public_html/page.php
```

works fine for me, edit the numbers as you like